# Flex 4 - What is meant by skinning and what is meant by custom components?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I want to know what is skinning and what is custom components? I know this is so chilly question. But I would like know about it. And where we have to use skinning and where we have to use custom components? If it has any similarities , please tell me about it.

I just want the clear explanation about these two things.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skinning -

For example, dropdownlist open dropdown, which has default hovered color, selected color, etc. which you have to change according to your application, then you can change it by skinning the dropdownlist component...

Custom component -

For example, button component has default events like, click event, mouse evnt, etc. and according to your application you have to remove some of events or modify some then create button with your event...

Please check below links...which will help you more...

[Need the example to use custom component in FLEX application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602644/need-the-example-to-use-custom-component-in-flex-application)

http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/01/creating-a-custom-component-and-skins-in-flex-4/

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. It's so clear answer. And if you know some other example of both, please mention it. It will so help's to me. And thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Skinning is about the look and feel of the application. What colors to use, drops shadows etc.

Custom component is tweaking an existing widget, combining widgets or creating a new one from scratch to achieve functionality that does not exist in the standard Sdk. Good examples of custom components are charts from 3rd party vendors

Comment: okay. we have button control. But somebody create's custom Buttons. Why we need it? And please tell me example like for both. Thank you for reply.

Comment: You could create a custom button to add functionality but it is rarely necessary. If you want it to look a certain way you use styles/css/skins if you want it to react differently you use events. Now if you want it to behave differently then it easier to subclass and create a custom button.

Comment: Do you know any example link for both skinning and custom components? Please share with me. Thank you.

Comment: See Jiya's link http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/01/creating-a-custom-component-and-skins-in-flex-4/ and http://demo.borland.com/flex/SilkTest13.0/3.4/Flex3TestApp/Flex3TestApp.html

Comment: Wow.. It's really superb example for flex3 components. And I need flex4 examples for both. If you know, please share. Thank you so much.

Comment: Last comment. There is no component explorer for flex 4 but Adobe did create Tour de flex http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html